# How to map the values inside a list with an integer in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am so fresh in Scala and Functional Programming. And I am stuck  with an operation with collections in Scala. I have a variable like that:

```
    val res4: List[(List[Double], Option[Int])] = 
List(
(List(4.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.5, 4.0),1998), 
(List(3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.5, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0).2000,
.......
)
```

I want to have a map or something like that by using each score in the list:

```
(4.0, 1998),
(2.0, 1998),
(3.0, 1998),
(4.0, 1998),
(3.0, 1998),
(2.5, 1998),
(4.0, 1998),
(3.0, 1998),
....
```

How can i do that?

Furhermore, If you know the tip about how to transform Some(1998) into 1998, I will be so appreciated.

Comment: Before transform Some(1998) to 1998 you must understand how handle None value. see https://alvinalexander.com/scala/using-scala-option-some-none-idiom-function-java-null/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [flatMap](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/collection-scala-flatmap-examples-map-flatten/):

```
List(
    (List(4.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.5, 4.0), Some(1998)),
    (List(3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.5, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0), Some(2000))
  )
    .flatMap(row => row._1.map(number => (number, row._2)))
    .foreach(it => println(it))
```

Comment: thx so much, it worked! And, I started to understand how map/flapmap works.